# Get width of two inline inputs

Tags: javascript, html

Having two inputs, inline, like this:

```
+------------+  +--------------------------+
| ID='inputA'|  |       ID='inputB'        |
+------------+  +--------------------------+

+------------------------------------------+
                    A
```

How can I get distance A in pixels using javascript?

I can't just add their widths since there is a small gap in the middle.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you target the container which is a parent of both?

Comment: wrap them in an inline / inline block element and get the width of that instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are next to each other, it should be possible to geht the distance using `.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
const startX = in1.getBoundingClientRect().x;
const endX = in2.getBoundingClientRect().x + in2.getBoundingClientRect().width;

const A = endX - startX
```

Comment: I know I am not supposed to say thank you on comments but.. thank you!! This was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Take any input element and get its parent element and get its width

```
document.getElementById("inputA").parentElement.clientWidth;
```

Comment: But that only works when there is nothing else inside the parent, right?

Answer (score -1):

Put both inputs in a span for example >>>>>  after that use jquery to take span.width()